# Not able to make Dapper query mapping case insensitive

Tags: .net, dapper

```
string query = $@"SELECT m.* FROM Table1";   
return await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Job>();
```

In Oracle database table `Table1` contains many columns and I do not want to specify all of them. Columns are returned in `UPPERCASE`, but in .NET we use CamelCase (`IsActive` etc.). In a result uppercase columns are never mapped to CamelCase in code.
(In reality query is more complex and there is also some custom maps and splitOn option).

Is it possible to solve with Dapper?

Answer (score 7):

Dapper's SqlMapper should be ***case-insensitive***

You can test it with:

```
public class Result
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestCaseSensitivity()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=test"))
        {
            var result = await conn.QueryFirstAsync<Result>("select ID = 1, VALUE = 'hello world'");
            Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
            Assert.That(result.Value, Is.EqualTo("hello world"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Dapper is case sensitive (as C# is). You should use FluentMap that gives all the flexibility you need to map database columns to class attributes:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.FluentMap